# can't remove PHPMyAdmin folder : "rm: cannot remove... Operation not permitted"

Tags: permissions, uninstall

There is folder come with `XAMPP` called `(PHPMyAdmin)`, I can't remove it from my PC and I don't have any permission, Access under the owner is (no list, no `create/delete`, no access) and under Group is (None) and for Security context is (unknown), therefore how can I remove this folder.

As `root` I tried the remove the folder, I got the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove '/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/tbl_gis_visualization.php': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Try `sudo rm -rf /path/to/PHPMyAdmin`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the result of running `ls -lsa` in one folder above the folder you can't remove

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/985826/edit) and show us exactly which steps you take in order to remove that folder.

Comment: please [edit] your question with the result of `lsattr /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/tbl_gis_visualization.php`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to be `root` to remove files in that location, that's if we're talking `/opt/lampp/` location here. To remove that folder use `sudo` to run the command as `root`:

```
sudo rm -rf /path/to/PHPMyAdmin
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `immutable flag` is on.

You can execute the below in order to modify it:

```
sudo chattr -i /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/tbl_gis_visualization.php
```

[man chattr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chattr.1.html)

> **chattr - change file attributes on a Linux file system**
>
> **A file with the `i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be  deleted or  renamed**,  no  link  can  be created to this file and no
>   data can be written to the file.  Only the superuser or a  process 
>   possessing  the        CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear
>   this attribute.

---

Similar issues in `PHPAdmin` were a file in phpadmin was flagged as `immutable` and `chattr` was used in order to allow delete the file:

- [help-i-cant-delete-phpmyadmins-setup-php](https://roadha.us/2011/02/help-i-cant-delete-phpmyadmins-setup-php.html) -
- [Cannot-edit-config-inc-php-Can-t-open-file-for-writing](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000849753-Cannot-edit-config-inc-php-Can-t-open-file-for-writing)

---

@GeorgeUdosen question in the below comment:

- Does the `-i` flag on a file prevent root from removing the parent folder?

Answer: Setting the `+i` flag on a file prevent root from removing the parent folder.

```
$ mkdir alx
$ cd alx/
$ sudo chattr +i xyz 
[sudo] password for [snip]: 
$ sudo rm xyz 
rm: cannot remove 'xyz': Operation not permitted
$ cd ..
$ sudo rm -rf alx/
rm: cannot remove 'alx/xyz': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Does the `-i` flag on a file prevent root from removing the parent folder?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - Yes, the +i flag prevent root from removing the parent folder.  See example in my updated answer

Comment: Funny mine got rid of the parent folder even when `-i` was set on one of the files!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - did you set `-i` or `+i` on the file?

Comment: Yes I did and it removed that parent folder!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - Interesting what is the source of the difference between our systems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70148/discussion-between-yaron-and-george-udosen).